# Two UITableViews in the same UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to have 2 table views on the same view. They both are within the same `UIViewController` which implementes the `UITableViewDelegate` and `Datasource`. one of the tableviews is static and the other is dynamic. The dynamic table view is loading just fine using the methods from its datasource, but the static one is showing up blank. Normally I erase the datasource methods from the controller so the static TableView doesn't override what's already done on the storyboard, but now I can't because those methods are being used by the dynamic TableView.

How can I have both of then under the same controller?

Answer (score 1):

As Putz says, you can set up your view controller to manage 2 table views by setting up your data source and delegate methods to check the table view that's passed in.

However, I don't think you can use static table views with anything but a UITableViewController, and a table view controller only knows how to manage a single table view.

The trick is to add 2 container views to your view controller that will contain 2 table views, and embed a different UITableViewController into each container view. Then each table view is managed by it's own table view controller. I have a project on github that does exactly this:  https://github.com/DuncanMC/test

I've set up protocols that the parent view controller and the 2 table view controllers use to communicate, although you don't have to do that if your needs are simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest option, that let's you keep a single VC for your delegate/datasource :

Set both tableviews delegate and datasource to your `UIViewController`.

Ctrl-drag from one of the static cells to your .h file, and create an IBOutlet collection ( called here `staticCellsCollection`). Add each static cell to **this** collection, careful with the order, it will be important.

Implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` this way :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView == _dynamicTableView) {
        // Do your dynamic thing
    }

    else if (tableView == _staticTableView) {
        // Return the static cells one by one
        // Here the static TV has only one section, and all cells are in staticCellsCollection
        return staticCellsCollection[indexPath.row];
    }

}
```

You also need to adapt `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionInTableView` but this is pretty basic (check which table is asking, and return appropriate values, for example `staticCellsCollection.count` for the number of rows of the static TV).

You may need to adapt this, for example if you want multiple sections in your static TableView, you should create an IBOutletCollection for each section, and handle the number of rows/sections accordingly, and return the correct cells. Anyway, this is pretty straightforward to implement once you get the idea.

Comment: i got the whole idea and seems pretty nice :O, could you please tell more about how i add the cells to the staticcellscollection

Comment: You control-drag the first cell of the static TV from your storyboard to your .h file, just as you usually create an IBOutlet. Instead of creating an outlet, you create an outlet collection (you can change it in the little pop-up window when you release the ctrl-drag). Then, for each other cell, you ctrl-drag from the cell to the same outlet collection you just created

Answer (score 0):

You can have two tableView's use the same delegate functions.  It's not amazingly pretty, but you can:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)inTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(inTableView == tableView1)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if
        ...
}
```

Put that type of logic into every tableView delegate function.

Comment: yeah, im doing that.... the case is that i have 3 table views and thats what im doing, the problem is with the static one, because the static table methods doesn't need to be coded, so you just delete the datasource codes and it works. what i want is one of this: what should be the code inside the (if static_table) how i tell him to use the cells i defined on the storyboard? or how do i assign another datasource to it?

Comment: I don't use storyboard, so I really have no idea how to help you with that problem.  Easiest solution is to create a tableviewdelegate class for that one only and setup custom delegate methods there that the other two dynamic tables don't use.